# Flutter Web Image upload to Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
// import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';

class AddBlogPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddBlogPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddBlogPage> createState() => _AddBlogPageState();
}

class _AddBlogPageState extends State<AddBlogPage> {
  TextEditingController titleTextController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController descTextController = TextEditingController();
  // File? _pickedImage;

  String? imgUrl;

  File? _imageFile;
  final FirebaseStorage _storage =
      FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(bucket: 'your-bucket-url.appspot.com');

  Future<void> _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: source,
      maxWidth: 600,
      maxHeight: 600,
      imageQuality: 85,
    );

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        log('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> _uploadFile() async {
    try {
      // Create a unique filename for the image
      String fileName = Path.basename(_imageFile!.path);
      Reference firebaseStorageRef =
          _storage.ref().child('blog/$fileName');
      UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile!);
      await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => log('File uploaded'));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      log(e.message.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: Get.height * 0.85,
      width: Get.width * 0.5,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          titleSpacing: 40,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.cancel_outlined,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 34,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 10)
          ],
          title: const Text(
            "Create Blog",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Form(
                child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => _pickImage(ImageSource.gallery),
                      child: Text('Select Image'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    _imageFile == null
                        ? const Text('No image selected.', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                        : const Text('Image Selected. Now upload the image', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: _imageFile == null ? null : _uploadFile,
                      child: Text('Upload Image'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  maxLines: 2,
                  controller: titleTextController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Enter Blog Title",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Colors.grey),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.lightGreenAccent, width: 2.0),
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)))),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  maxLines: 10,
                  controller: descTextController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Enter Blog Description",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Colors.grey),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.lightGreenAccent, width: 2.0),
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)))),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (imgUrl != null) {
                      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('blog')
                          .doc()
                          .set({
                        'image': imgUrl,
                        'title': titleTextController.text,
                        'description': descTextController.text,
                      });
                      Get.back();
                      log(imgUrl!);
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text("Upload Blog"),
                )
              ],
            )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Future<void> _pickImage() async {
  //   Reference referenceRoot = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
  //   Reference referenceDirImage = referenceRoot.child('blog');

  //   final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  //   XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  //   if (image != null) {
  //     var tempImage = await image.readAsBytes();
  //     Uint8List? localImage;
  //     String? productImageUrlFileType;

  //     FilePickerResult? imageFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
  //     if (imageFile != null) {
  //       Uint8List bytes = imageFile.files[0].bytes!;
  //       setState(() {
  //         localImage = bytes;
  //         productImageUrlFileType = imageFile.files.first.extension;
  //       });
  //     }

  //     setState(() async {
  //       imgUrl = await uploadImage(folderName: 'blog', fileBytes: localImage!, fileType: productImageUrlFileType!);
  //     });

  //     // setState(() async {
  //     //   Reference referenceImageToUpload = referenceDirImage.child(image.name);

  //     //   try {
  //     //     referenceImageToUpload.putFile(File(image.name));

  //     //     imgUrl = await referenceImageToUpload.getDownloadURL();

  //     //   } catch (e) {
  //     //     log(e.toString());
  //     //   }
  //     // });
  //   } else {
  //     log('No image has been selected!');
  //   }
  // }

//   Future<String?> uploadImage(
//       {required String folderName,
//       required Uint8List fileBytes,
//       required String fileType,
//       BuildContext? context}) async {
//     String? imgUrl;

//     final metadata = SettableMetadata(contentType: fileType);
//     try {
//       TaskSnapshot reference = await FirebaseStorage.instance
//           .ref()
//           .child('$folderName/${DateTime.now().toString()}')
//           .putData(fileBytes, metadata)
//           .whenComplete(() async {});
//       imgUrl = await reference.ref.getDownloadURL();
//     } catch (e) {
//       showDialog(
//           barrierDismissible: false,
//           context: context!,
//           builder: ((context) => AlertDialog(
//                 title: const Text("Updated "),
//                 actions: [
//                   TextButton(
//                       onPressed: () {
//                         Navigator.pop(context);
//                         Navigator.pop(context);
//                       },
//                       child: const Text("OK"))
//                 ],
//               )));
//       log("error while uploadin image $e");
//     }

//     return imgUrl;
//   }

}



// Future<String> uploadImage() async {
//   final html.FileUploadInputElement input = html.FileUploadInputElement();
//   input.accept = 'image/*'; // limit file selection to images
//   input.click();

//   await input.onChange.first;

//   final file = input.files!.first;
//   final fileName = file.name;
//   final destination = 'images/$fileName';
//   final ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(destination);
//   await ref.putBlob(file);
//   final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
//   log(url.toString());
//   return url;
// }
```

I've tried using many methods but didn't find any solution. Using this code I can select the image but couldn't able to upload the image to firebase. So, please help me with uploading the image from local storage to flutter web, and from flutter web, it should upload the image to Firebase storage.

So, please help me with the following codebase.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `putFile` method use `putData` method and pass image bytes.

Change this

`UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile!);`

to this

```
Uint8List imageData = await pickedFile!.readAsBytes();
UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putData(imageData);
```

Comment: Hi Bro it didn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/TanmoyTSSaha/barsha-fm-admin.git

Comment: This is the git repository can you check please

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes while uploading the image it's not accepting the image it's not giving any exception but giving some unusual logs.

Comment: Did you saw the code?